# Enable file downloads in wordpress only for logged in users from another platform?

Tags: wordpress, handshake, download-manager

My client has a Wordpress website and he wants to upload a specific catalogue so customer can download it only when they log in with their username and password from another managing platform called Handshake. He uses this platform to manage his clients, payments, inventory and such.

He would like to see if we can use the sign-in form from Handshake to allow downloads, using their existing accounts from Handshake instead of asking clients to create another accounts on Wordpress.

I am wondering if there is a way to integrate this Handshake log-in into Wordpress. Any other suggestions are also appreciated.

Thank you very much.